# Find which product is often ordered with her one in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a powerbi report containing a table that looks like :

| Product ID | Transaction ID | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | X | 1 |
| B | X | 2 |
| C | X | 1 |
| A | Y | 2 |
| B | Y | 1 |
| A | Z | 1 |
| C | Z | 1 |

I would like to create a new table in dax, that would show for each unique occurence of the prodcut ID in the previous table, each product that has been bought at the same time (=in a transaction), and the sum of qty associated.

So for the example above, that would give a table like :

| Product ID | Associated Product ID | Qty | Count of Transactions |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 3 | 2 |
| A | C | 2 | 2 |
| B | A | 3 | 2 |
| B | C | 1 | 1 |
| C | A | 2 | 2 |
| C | B | 2 | 1 |

I hope this is clear enough.

In SQL I could probably pull it off, but I have no idea how to this in DAX (using a DAX generated table)

Can somebody help me out ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this may be a little tricky and I don't know how it performs on a large dataset. I use GENERATE to create Main and AssociatedProduct (the first step create a corssjoin!), then we pack MainProd to variable to generate virtualtable with all transaction id (__Trans). Then we can easly compare [AssociatedProd] with source ProductId and Transaction with our __Trans. In the end, I remove SelfRelation (Product A vs Product A).

```
AssocAgg = 
FILTER (
    GENERATE (
        SELECTCOLUMNS (
            VALUES ( Associated[Product ID] ),
            "MainProd", Associated[Product ID]
        ),
        VAR __Main = [MainProd]
        VAR __Trans =
            CALCULATETABLE (
                VALUES ( Associated[Transaction ID] ),
                Associated[Product ID] = __Main
            )
        RETURN
            ADDCOLUMNS (
                SELECTCOLUMNS (
                    VALUES ( Associated[Product ID] ),
                    "AssociatedProd", Associated[Product ID]
                ),
                "Trans",
                    CALCULATE (
                        COUNTROWS ( VALUES ( Associated[Transaction ID] ) ),
                        FILTER (
                            Associated,
                            [AssociatedProd] = Associated[Product ID]
                                && Associated[Transaction ID] IN __Trans
                        )
                    ),
                "qty",
                    CALCULATE (
                        SUM ( Associated[Qty] ),
                        FILTER (
                            Associated,
                            [AssociatedProd] = Associated[Product ID]
                                && Associated[Transaction ID] IN __Trans
                        )
                    )
            )
    ),
    [AssociatedProd] <> [MainProd]
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately I have tried it and after 2+ hours of calculation I still don't have a result. The table has 247000 rows so I guess this is why

Comment: This may depend on how many unique ProductID do you have for each we generate a table (with transaction IDs). If you have a very wide table Associated, then you can in filter replace table name with ALL(AssociatedProduct ID], Associated[Transaction ID]).


However, it may turn out that it will have to be done on a source database, e.g. with a sql query.

Comment: or you may try to duplicate your table with productid and transaction ID, create relationship many to many; then create some calculations to get qty and number of transaction